# CCM logs reading last few Log Text lines

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if there is a way to only get selected object of a content for the last x number of lines. In this example, last 5 lines. Below is the command I am using.

```
Get-Content "C:\Windows\CCM\Logs\DataTransferService.log" | Select-Object -Last 5
```

When running this command on any ccm log files when the last line (highlighted under Log Text) has multiple lines in a thread, it counts those thread lines as 5 lines. Thus my result does not display the last lines with text DTSjob. Also, the command works as expected as long as the last line does not have a thread with multiple lines. So if there's a way to only display Last x number of log text line without displaying the threads it would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe those extra lines are tab delimited. You could just filter those out before sending to `Select-Object`.

```
Get-Content DataTransferService.log |
    Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "\t"} |
        Select-Object -Last 5
```

Comment: Also, use `-tail` to only get the last X lines. You don't want to read the whole file and pass it down the pipeline, just read the last 10 or 15, then filter for tabs, and select the last 5.

Comment: Thank you. I added the -Tail parameter for x number of lines. Also, is there anyway to highlight "0x800706D9" if it does show up in the log? I just realized I'm at where I wanted in terms of looking for logs with last few lines but the text are still uneasy for the eyes.